# How to get the key name to be coded for keymap in vimrc?

Tags: vim, keymap

In Emacs, I can press <kbd>Ctrl-h</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd>, to describe a key. I can get the key name even it's undefined, e.g.,

```
C-x <C-M-end> is undefined
```

Thus, I got to know the key name is `C-x <C-M-end>`.

But how can you get the key name for Vim?

I want to setup a keymap for <kbd>Ctrl-Shift-V</kbd> and <kbd>Shift-Insert</kbd>, but what the code shall I have to use?

Is it possible to get the key name on the fly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest I can find to `describe-key` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>K</kbd>) is the `:map` command.  It will list all mappings.

You can also run `:map <key name>`, but you have to specify `<key>` using the special syntax listed in
[key-notation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#key-notation).

Or you can try `:map`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>`<key>`, which should let you just press the key rather than needing to use the special syntax.

So to bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, try this:

`:map <C-S-v> whatever`

or

`:map`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> `whatever`

But make sure that your terminal program doesn't already use this for something special like paste, otherwise Vim will never see the key press.

Also see [map-alt-keys](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:map-alt-keys), which helps explain whether your <kbd>Alt</kbd> key should be written as `<M-x>` or `<A-x>`.

Comment: It's Ctrl-h,k, not Ctrl-X,k which means kill buffer.

Comment: Sorry, fixed that.

Comment: I'm not sure if `M` or `A` will be mapped to `Alt`.  But `<M-h>, <M-l>` just don't work. I don't know whether the key name is invalid, or the key events haven't been sent to Vim. No log, no clue.

Comment: Yes, `Alt` is difficult, because most terminals send `ESC` then `x` when `Alt+x` is pressed, and how does Vim know you didn't press `ESC` then `x`.  Basically `Alt` only works in Gvim.

Answer (score 6):

To find out what a key or key combination outputs in Vim, I usually open a blank buffer with "`:enew`", enter insert mode, press <kbd>control-v</kbd>, then the key or key combination I want to identify.  This control-v trick can also work on the :-command line, so defining mappings for testing is fairly easy.  For example, "`:map` ", <kbd>control-v</kbd> and the key combination, " `:echo 'it works'`".

Answer (score 1):

Just type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> on-the-fly and the keys you wish to press. If you don't found the result expected (like for instance `<c-space>`, `<c-cr>`, `<M-i>`, ...) it just means you are using vim and not gvim. The way vim understands the keys typed is tied to the configuration of your terminal(s). gvim uses its own definitions, there is thus nothing to configure.